# Using Selenium in Python to Login

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

I am trying to use Selenium in Python to try and log into this website

```
https://commerce.spscommerce.com/auth/login/
```

All of the xpath's I have tried were not able to locate the element.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://commerce.spscommerce.com/auth/login/")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="username"]').send_keys("test")
```

I tried using name, type and class but have not been able to locate the element.
Here is the HTML I got from inspect element

```
<input id="username" name="username" type="email" required="" ng-model="ctrl.email" ng-
blur="ctrl.checkEmail($event, ctrl.email)" ng-focus="ctrl.resetEmailBoolean()" autofocus="" 
test="login-username" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-valid-email ng-valid-required ng-touched">
```

Any Ideas on what path to use to locate the element and send the username/password? Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Email Address* field is within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    driver.get('https://commerce.spscommerce.com/auth/login/')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src^='https://commerce.spscommerce.com/auth-app']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#username"))).send_keys("test")
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    driver.get("https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/msft/interactive-chart?timeframe=5d")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[contains(@src, 'edgar-chartiq')]")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='btn hideSmallIR stx-collapsible' and @id='dataTableBtn']/span[text()='Data Table']"))).click()
    ```
  - **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

    ```
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: spscommerce]

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant discussion in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)